# Google API Distance Matrix macro tool for excel

Tags: excel, google-maps-api-3, google-api, xmlhttprequest, distance

I dispose a macro tool that I used for the distance calculation between different points in Excel. However since Google API started billing the service it is out of use.

I have created a google API key but for the moment I am stuck at this step, it says that the method open of the object 'IXMLHTTPRequest' has failed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODXT4.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZDcG.png

Could you please help me on that?

Here is the entire script of my macro:

---

```
Sub Calculer(Départ As String, Arrivée As String, Distance As String, Temps As Double)

Dim surl As String
Dim oXH As Object
Dim bodytxt As String

'Utilisation de l'API Google

Distance = ""
Temps = 0
Départ = Replace(Départ, " ", "+")
Départ = SupprimerAccents(Départ)
Arrivée = Replace(Arrivée, " ", "+")
Arrivée = SupprimerAccents(Arrivée)

surl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & _
Départ & "&destinations=" & Arrivée & _
"&mode=driving&sensor=false&units=metric"

Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")

With oXH
.Open "get", surl, False
.send
bodytxt = .responseText
End With

bodytxt = Right(bodytxt, Len(bodytxt) - InStr(1, bodytxt, "<text>") - 5)
If InStr(1, bodytxt, "</text>") <> 0 Then Temps_Texte = Left(bodytxt, InStr(1, bodytxt, "</text>") - 1)
If Temps_Texte <> "" Then
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " weeks", "w")
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " week", "w")
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " day", "j")
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " hours", "h")
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " hour", "h")
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " mins", "m")
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " min", "m")
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " seconds", "s")
    Temps_Texte = Replace(Temps_Texte, " second", "s")
    Heure = Split(Temps_Texte, " ")
    j = 0
    On Error GoTo fin
    If Right(Heure(j), 1) = "w" Then Temps = Temps + Val(Heure(j)) * 7: j = j + 1
    If Right(Heure(j), 1) = "d" Then Temps = Temps + Val(Heure(j)): j = j + 1
    If Right(Heure(j), 1) = "h" Then Temps = Temps + Val(Heure(j)) / 24: j = j + 1
    If Right(Heure(j), 1) = "m" Then Temps = Temps + Val(Heure(j)) / 24 / 60: j = j + 1
    If Right(Heure(j), 1) = "s" Then Temps = Temps + Val(Heure(j)) / 24 / 60 / 60: j = j + 1
fin:
    On Error GoTo 0
End If


bodytxt = Right(bodytxt, Len(bodytxt) - InStr(1, bodytxt, "<text>") - 5)
If InStr(1, bodytxt, "</text>") <> 0 Then Distance = Left(bodytxt, InStr(1, bodytxt, "</text>") - 1)
If Distance = "" Then Distance = "Aucun résultat"

Distance = Replace(Distance, " km", "")
Distance = Replace(Distance, ",", "")

Set oXH = Nothing

End Sub

Function SupprimerAccents(ByVal sChaine As String) As String
'Fonction récupérée ici : http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1089902/logiciels/microsoft-office/excel/macros-vba-excel/suppression-accents-chaines-caracteres/
Dim sTmp As String, i As Long, p As Long
Const sCarAccent As String = "ÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const sCarSansAccent As String = "AAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyy"
    sTmp = sChaine
    For i = 1 To Len(sTmp)
        p = InStr(sCarAccent, Mid(sTmp, i, 1))
        If p > 0 Then Mid$(sTmp, i, 1) = Mid$(sCarSansAccent, p, 1)
    Next i
    SupprimerAccents = sTmp
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
surl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & _
Départ & "&destinations=" & Arrivée & _
"&mode=driving&sensor=false&units=metric"
```

Add your key (and remove the `&sensor=false`):

```
surl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & _
Départ & "&destinations=" & Arrivée & _
"&mode=driving&units=metric&key=MY_API_KEY"
```

Comment: Thanks it works! however I had to replace in the [.Open "get", surl, False] the surl with the "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & _
Départ & "&destinations=" & Arrivée & _
"&mode=driving&units=metric&key=MY_API_KEY" in order to make it work